# Why i cant install metasploit on termux with out root it always says like this

Tags: metasploit

Traceback (most recent call last):
ruby: No such file or directory -- /data/data/com.termux/files/home/metasploit-framework/msfconsole (LoadError)

Comment: Maybe you don't have enough space

Comment: I have morethan 10gb

Comment: Try installing `metasploit-framework`